# is it possible to create a facebook login page without facebook sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

i have created the login with facebook with the help of facebook sdk (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js). There is a method FB.login() to call login page...
I'm trying to implement it without facebook sdk.
Anyone here knows about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook suggests using Facebook's JavaScript SDK, which is the recommended method to add Facebook Login to your website.

If for some reason you can't use our JavaScript SDK you can also implement login without it. Check it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2?locale=en_GB